# JavaScript inheritance with super calls and mixins

Tags: javascript, inheritance, mixins

I needed JavaScript inheritance that offered calling of overridden methods (super calls).

Furthermore I needed a possibiliy to add behaviour to instances (mixins).

Mixins should not only be full classes including mentioned inheritance but also be able to override its instance' method.

Below is what I came up with. It does what I needed it to do. May I ask to have a look at the implementation and its possible shortcomings?

```js
log = function( s ) {
var dn = document.getElementById( "output" );
dn.innerHTML = dn.innerHTML + "</br>" + s;
}
function Class() { }
Class.prototype.construct = function() {};
Class.create = function() {
// create new instance
var oClass = arguments[0];
var args = arguments[1];
var oInstance = new oClass( args ); 
// in case of mixins add behaviour to instance
if( args && args.mixins ) {
 var c = args.mixins.length;
 // loop through mixins prototypes an attach
 for( var ix=0; ix<c; ix++ ) {
  var oMixin = args.mixins[ ix ].o.prototype;
  // set flag whether mixin has init function
  var bInit = false;
  for (var sMember in oMixin) {
   if( sMember == "_init" ) {
    // mixin has init fuction
    bInit = true;
   }
   else {
    var oMember = oMixin[sMember];                      
    if (oMember instanceof Function && 
        oInstance[sMember] ) {
     // in case of overrides save mixee's orig 
     // method and add _mixee() to call it
     if( ! oInstance.lfnMixee ) {
      oInstance.lfnMixee = {};
      oInstance._mixee = function() {
       var that = arguments[0];
       var args = arguments[1];
       var sfn = arguments[2];
       return that.lfnMixee[ sfn ].apply( that, args );
      };
     }
     var fn = oInstance[ sMember ];
     oInstance.lfnMixee[sMember] = fn;
    }
    // augment mixin's members
    oInstance[ sMember ] = oMember;
   }
  }
  if( bInit ) {
   // call mixin's init function with passed on arguments
   var aConfig = args.mixins[ ix ].aConfig;
   oMixin._init.apply( oInstance, [ aConfig ] );
  }
 }
}
if( oInstance._init ) {
 // call init function if exists
 oInstance._init( args );
}
return oInstance;
};
Class.extend = function(o) {
var oNew = function() {
 if (arguments[ 0 ] !== Class) {
  // call constructor if not base 
  this.construct.apply( this, arguments ); 
 }
};
// get prototype and hook to parent
var oPrototype = new this(Class);
var oParent = this.prototype;
for (var sMember in o) {
 var oMember = o[sMember];                      
 if (oMember instanceof Function) {
  oMember.oParent = oParent;
  // in case we override add method
  // _parent() to call parent's function
  oPrototype._parent = function() {
   var that = arguments[0];
   var args = arguments[1];
   var sfn = arguments[2];
   return args.callee.oParent[ sfn ].apply( that, args )
  };
 }
// augment with members
oPrototype[sMember] = oMember;
}
// set prototype
oNew.prototype = oPrototype;
// and make it extendable
oNew.extend = this.extend;      
return oNew;
};

/* ****** TEST CODE ********* */

var Person = Class.extend({
name : null,
_init : function( a ) {
 this.name = a.name;
},
say : function( s ) {
 s = '('+this.name+') "' + s +'"';
 log( s );
} 
});

var Moderator = Person.extend({
_init : function( a ) {
 this._parent( this, arguments, '_init' );
 this.name = "[mod|" + this.name +"]";
},
say : function( s ) {
 log( 'as moderator I say: ' );
 this._parent( this, arguments, 'say' );
},
read : function( s ) {
 s = "..."+s;
 log( s );
} 
});

var Megaphone = Class.extend({
say : function( s ) {
 log( "&lt;YELL&gt;" );
 this._mixee( this, arguments, 'say' );
 log( "&lt;/YELL&gt;" );
}
});

var Googles = Class.extend({
type : "Googles",
color : "transparent",
read : function() {
 log( "&lt;SHARP&gt;" );
 this._mixee( this, arguments, 'read' );
 log( "&lt;/SHARP&gt;" );
},
clean : function(){
 log( this.name + " cleaning "+ this.color +" " + this.type );
} 
});

var Shades = Googles.extend({
type : "Shades",
_init : function( a ) {
 this.color = a.color;
},
read : function() {
 log( "&lt;"+this.color+"&gt;" );
 this._parent( this, arguments, 'read' );
 log( "&lt;/"+this.color+"&gt;" );
},
clean : function(){
 this._parent( this, arguments, 'clean' );
} 
});

var john = Class.create( Person, {
name : "john",
mixins: [ {
 o : Googles
} ]
 } );

var joseph = Class.create( Moderator, { 
name : "joseph",
mixins: [ {
 o : Shades,
 aConfig : { color : "blue" }
 }
 , { o : Megaphone }
]
 } );

john.say( 'hello' );
john.clean();

log( '---------' );

joseph.say( 'hello' );
joseph.read( 'agenda of meeting' );
joseph.clean();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 has support for [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). It also has support for [super calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Super_class_calls_with_super) and [mixins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins). I highly recommend *you ditch this approach* and write future-proof code. You can always use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert ES6 code back to ES5-compliant code which most, if not all, browsers are supporting.

```
log = function( s ) {
```

There's no `var` keyword. Should you want to wrap this in a closure, this will shoot `log` back up the global scope.

```
var c = args.mixins.length;
// loop through mixins prototypes an attach
for( var ix=0; ix<c; ix++ ) {
```

`mixins` appear to be an array. Use `forEach` instead of a `for` loop. This way, you avoid creating the extra index variables. `forEach` provides its callback with the index of the item as the second argument.

```
for (var sMember in oMixin) {
```

`oMixin` appears to be an object. Suggesting you use `Object.keys()` in combination with `forEach` to loop through objects. `Object.keys()` provides the own enumerable keys like a `for-in` loop with a `hasOwnProperty` guard.

```
oMember instanceof Function
```

Consider using `typeof something === 'function'`. `typeof` is preferred over `instanceof` since you're just dealing with basic types, not custom instances of constructors. More on that in [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899574/which-is-best-to-use-typeof-or-instanceof#comment709665_899591).

Lastly, prefer composition (augmenting of objects) over inheritance (subclassing). I personally don't care which one's The Right Way™ since I work with projects that do either pretty well. However, inheritance forces you to create a taxonomy of things and assume you can foresee the future of your app.

But if something unexpected happens, like having some class that doesn't follow the taxonomy or wants to have functionality that exists in a separate branch of the hierarchy, you eventually resort to either duplication of code, or multiple inheritance. This makes your code, your architecture and the system that enables you to do it (ie: your code up there) to become really hairy. **TL;DR: Keep it simple.**

[Here's an example of augmentation using `Object.assign`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=%20%20%20%20function%20createPerson()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20'person'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20say%3A%20function(message)%7B%20alert(message)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20createModerator()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20subject%20%3D%20createPerson()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...subject%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20say%3A%20function(message)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subject.say(%60moderator%3A%24%7Bmessage%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20megaphoneMixin(subject)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...subject%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20say%3A%20function(message)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subject.say(message.toUpperCase())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20normalPerson%20%3D%20createPerson()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20moderatorPerson%20%3D%20createModerator()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20moderatorWithMegaphones%20%3D%20megaphoneMixin(createModerator())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20normalPerson.say('hello')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20moderatorPerson.say('hello')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20moderatorWithMegaphones%20.say('hello')%3B).

```
// Creates a person object.
function createPerson(){
  return {
    name: 'person',
    say: function(message){ alert(message); }
  };
}

// Create a moderator person that "inherits" a person. Essentially we just
// created an augmented version of the person, hijacking the say function.
function createModerator(){
  var subject = createPerson();
  return Object.assign({
    ...subject,
    say: function(message){
      subject.say(`moderator:${message}`);
    }
  });
}

// Example of a mixin. We augment the subject with a `say` function that
// also modifies the function. The difference with this and above is that
// the mixin accepts a subject dynamically while the above knows about
// the subject in advance, like you would in inheritance and mixins.
function megaphoneMixin(subject){
  return Object.assign({
    ...subject,
    say: function(message){
      subject.say(message.toUpperCase());
    }
  });
}

var normalPerson = createPerson();
var moderatorPerson = createModerator();
var moderatorWithMegaphones = megaphoneMixin(createModerator());

normalPerson.say('hello');
moderatorPerson.say('hello');
moderatorWithMegaphones .say('hello');
```